# When we have to annotate that function is payable in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, payable

I have used solidity smart contracts since 3 months ago,  but I never used the decorator "payable".

Is it sometimes necessary to use a payable function?

Answer (score 1):

Payable is necessary if you want the method to be able to receive funds or a "value".

For example, if I create a crowdsale-contract the payable function will be handling the receiving of the funds.

Comment: and what about if the method use a lot of gas ? isn't necessary to add payable decorator ?

Comment: Nope, gas has nothing to do with the payable decoration.